# JQuery won't change HTML of an id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

So I have a form and a script:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" id="contact">

  <label for="prenom">Prénom</label>
  <input type="text" id="prenom" name="prenom" placeholder="Votre prénom.." class="champ">
  <label for="nom">Nom</label>
  <input type="text" id="nom" name="nom" placeholder="Votre nom.." class="champ"><br/>

  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Votre nom.." class="champ"><br/>

  <label for="country">Pays</label>
  <select name="country" id="country" class="champ">
  <option value="france">France</option>
  <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
  <option value="Suisse">Suisse</option>
  <option value="Belgique">Belgique</option>
</select><br/>

  <label for="sujet">Sujet : </label>
  <textarea class="champ" name="sujet" id="sujet" placeholder="Exprimez-vous.." style="height:200px;     width=600px;"></textarea ><br/>

<input type="submit" value="Envoyer" class="champ" id="envoi">
  </form>
        <div id="errorMessage"></div>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            var errorMessage="";
            $("#envoi").click(function () {
                if($("#prenom").val()==""){
                    errorMessage+="<p>Remplissez votre prénom!</p>";
                }
                if($("#nom").val()==""){
                    errorMessage+="<p>Remplissez votre nom!</p>";
                }
                if($("#email").val()==""){
                    errorMessage+="<p>Remplissez votre email!</p>";
                }
                if($("#pays").val()==""){
                    errorMessage+="<p>Sélectionnez votre pays!</p>";
                }
                if($("#sujet").val()==""){
                    errorMessage+="<p>Remplissez votre message!</p>";
                }
                if(errorMessage!=""){
                    alert("hey");
                    $("#errorMessage").html(errorMessage);
                }
            });
        </script>
```

I have a problem with this :

```
if(errorMessage!=""){
    alert("hey");
    $("#errorMessage").html(errorMessage);
}
```

I wish it would display the error message in

right before the script. The program does get into the if condition, because the alert appears. However, it does not display the error.

What am I doing wrong please?
Thanks,

Comment: What happens if you do `alert('error message = ' + errorMessage)`? what is the output.

Comment: Because it's submitting the form already

Answer (score 1):

It's due to your page is being reloaded after being submitted.
If you want to display an error (validation) you should return false.

```
if(errorMessage!=""){
    alert("hey");
    $("#errorMessage").html(errorMessage);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

simply just add the following  in your code to Acheive your goal

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Here is the working jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/1b5pcqpL/

Answer (score 0):

The button trigger you are using is of `type=submit` which is causing your form to submit.

Instead try using `type=button` and submit the form after jquery validation.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" id="contact">

  <label for="prenom">Prénom</label>
  <input type="text" id="prenom" name="prenom" placeholder="Votre prénom.." class="champ">
  <label for="nom">Nom</label>
  <input type="text" id="nom" name="nom" placeholder="Votre nom.." class="champ"><br/>

  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Votre nom.." class="champ"><br/>

  <label for="country">Pays</label>
  <select name="country" id="country" class="champ">
  <option value="france">France</option>
  <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
  <option value="Suisse">Suisse</option>
  <option value="Belgique">Belgique</option>
</select><br/>

  <label for="sujet">Sujet : </label>
  <textarea class="champ" name="sujet" id="sujet" placeholder="Exprimez-vous.." style="height:200px;     width=600px;"></textarea ><br/>

<input type="button" value="Envoyer" class="champ" id="envoi">
  </form>
        <div id="errorMessage"></div>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            
            $("#envoi").click(function () {
                 var errorMessage="";
                if($("#prenom").val()==""){
                    errorMessage+="<p>Remplissez votre prénom!</p>";
                }
                if($("#nom").val()==""){
                    errorMessage+="<p>Remplissez votre nom!</p>";
                }
                if($("#email").val()==""){
                    errorMessage+="<p>Remplissez votre email!</p>";
                }
                if($("#pays").val()==""){
                    errorMessage+="<p>Sélectionnez votre pays!</p>";
                }
                if($("#sujet").val()==""){
                    errorMessage+="<p>Remplissez votre message!</p>";
                }
                if(errorMessage!=""){
                    alert("hey");
                    $("#errorMessage").html(errorMessage);
                }
      else{
          $("#contact").submit();
      }
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT, that did it. however, how come it works in this example from the Web Developper Course 2.0:

Comment: see my other answer

Answer (score 0):

The message is appended to the DOM, what happens is that the form get submitted and that causing the page to reload (happens so fast you can't notice it). You'll have to prevent the default behavior of the event (which is submitting the form right after the alert and the message is appended to the DOM)!

**Note:** Change your `click` event to the `submit` event to prevent the user from submitting via enter key as well.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#contact").submit(function (event) { // listen to the submit event on the form #contact itself (event is needed so we can prevent its default behavior)
        var errorMessage = ""; // this should be here

        // ...

        if(errorMessage != ""){
            alert("hey");
            $("#errorMessage").html(errorMessage);
            event.preventDefault(); // stop the submit (we encountered an error so mission abort :D)
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>

    <title>jQuery</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">

        body {

            font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size:130%;

        }

        input {

            padding: 5px 5px 12px 5px;
            font-size: 25px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            border: 1px solid grey;
            width:320px;

            }

        label {

            position: relative;
            top:12px;
            width:200px;
            float: left;

        }

        #wrapper {

            width: 550px;
            margin: 0 auto;


        }

        .form-element {

            margin-bottom: 10px;

        }

        #submitButton {

            width: 130px;
            margin-left: 200px;
        }

        #errorMessage {

            color: red;
            font-size: 90% !important;

        }

        #successMessage {

            color: green;
            font-size: 90% !important;
            display:none;
            margin-bottom:20px;

        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="successMessage">You've done it! Congratulations.</div>

        <div id="errorMessage"></div>

        <div class="form-element">

            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder = "eg. yourname@gmail.com">

            </div>

        <div class="form-element">

            <label for="phone">Telephone</label>
            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder = "eg. 0123456789">

        </div>

        <div class="form-element">

            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password">

        </div>

        <div class="form-element">

            <label for="passwordConfirm">Confirm Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="passwordConfirm" id="passwordConfirm">

        </div>

         <div class="form-element">

            <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Sign Up"

        </div>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function isEmail(email) {

            var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

            return regex.test(email);

        }

        $("#submitButton").click(function() {

            var errorMessage = "";
            var fieldsMissing = "";

            if ($("#email").val() == "") {

                fieldsMissing += "<br>Email";

            }

            if ($("#phone").val() == "") {

                fieldsMissing += "<br>Telephone";

            }

            if ($("#password").val() == "") {

                fieldsMissing += "<br>Password";

            }

            if ($("#passwordConfirm").val() == "") {

                fieldsMissing += "<br>Confirm Password";

            }

            if (fieldsMissing != "") {

                errorMessage += "<p>The following field(s) are missing:" + fieldsMissing;

            }

            if (isEmail($("#email").val()) == false) {

                errorMessage += "<p>Your email address is not valid</p>";

            }

            if ($.isNumeric($("#phone").val()) == false) {

                errorMessage += "<p>Your phone number is not numeric</p>"

            }

            if ($("#password").val() != $("#passwordConfirm").val()) {

                errorMessage += "<p>Your passwords don't match</p>";

            }

            if (errorMessage != "") {

                $("#errorMessage").html(errorMessage);

            } else {

                $("#successMessage").show();
                $("#errorMessage").hide();

            }

        });


    </script>

</body>
```

How come it works in this case?

Comment: Here you have not used `<form>` tag.